# What do duplicate iptables rules do?

Tags: networking, iptables

I am trying to better understand the way Docker wires up the network and came across this question.  Note: I don't believe this has anything to do with Docker per se, that was only the vehicle under which it came up.  Please feel free to correct if this is a misperception on my part!

With Docker up and running in Swarm mode, the following iptables command is executed:

```
> iptables -t filter -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION  all  --  anywhere      anywhere
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere     (1)     anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere     (2)     anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere     (3)     anywhere
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere     (4)     anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

I added the 1,2,3,4 numbers in the output.  Numbers 1 and 4 seem to be duplicates.  Likewise, 2 and 3 seem like exact copies of one another.  What is the purpose of these?  Are they really duplicates?  If not, how do I see the next level of information which would then discern them?

Separately, in the first section, if anyone can explain `dpt:domain` vs `dpt:bootps` that would be cool too!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rule "pairs" 1-4 and 2-3 you noted are most likely not duplicates, but you can't see the differences in the output of the command you used. if you use `iptables -L -v` you will get additional output that may reveal the differences - this usually occurs (in my experience) when the rules are operating on different interfaces.

The `dpt:domain` and `dpt:bootps` are different destination port specifications. `dpt:domain` is destination port 53 (domain, or DNS), while `dpt:bootps` is destination port 67 (DHCP).

Edit: you are correct, this situation has nothing to do with Docker directly. It's a relatively common situation that was exposed by Docker in your environment, but occurs outside of a Docker environment just as often.

Answer (score 1):

To give a supplement answer to your second question: Running `iptables -L -n` would return IP addresses and ports in numeric format and not translating them into hostnames and service names. As such `dpt:domain` and `dpt:bootps` would be printed as `dpt:53` and `dpt:67`. This applies to every host/port you are not aware of the servicename behind.